# LuaLaTeX: Font shape unedfined, using otherfont instead

Tags: fonts, luatex

World!

I'm writing my CV using LuaLaTeX. Everything works, the code compiles fine. 
Yet I get two warnings, related to my problem:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/RobotoLight(0)/m/it' undefined
```

Naturally my resulting problem is, whenever I use

```
\textit{RandomText}
```

the text is printed as normal font. I did install Roboto Light Italic though.
Does anyone can tell me where the path 'TU/RobotoLight(0)/m/it' is leading to?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}       % for fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily{\cvnamefont}{Roboto Medium}
\newfontfamily{\cvsectionfont}{Roboto Medium}
\newfontfamily{\cvtitlefont}{Roboto Regular}
\newfontfamily{\cvdurationfont}{Roboto Light Italic}
\newfontfamily{\cvheadingfont}{Roboto Regular}
\setmainfont{Roboto Light}

\begin{document}
\textit{Hello, World!}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fontspec seems not to be able to find the italic on its own. But you can help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}       % for fonts
\setmainfont{Roboto Light}[ItalicFont=Roboto-LightItalic]

\begin{document}
Hallo \textit{Hello, World!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ulrike!